# Error "unexpected symbol in ..." within R function definition

Tags: r

```
mymean<-function(x){mm<-sum(x[is.finite(x)])/length(x[is.finite(x)])return(mm)}
```

what's the error in the above mentioned code

I tried running it but there it showed error : `unexpected symbol in the code`.

Can you help me finding the why there is error

Comment: Please format your code as code in the future and not as  plain text.

Answer (score 3):

The R engine cannot parse/understand your function definition because it is all in one line without the separation of single statements. It tries to interpret `length(..)return(..)` as one expression, which it is not able to do.

Either split your function over multiple lines

```
mymean<-function(x) 
{ 
    mm<-sum(x[is.finite(x)])/length(x[is.finite(x)])
    return(mm) 
}
```

or use a semicolon as a separator

```
mymean<-function(x) { mm<-sum(x[is.finite(x)])/length(x[is.finite(x)]); return(mm) }
```

Tried with R 3.6.1 and RStudio 2023-06.2 Build 561

Comment: Could also just be `function(x) sum(x[is.finite(x)])/length(x[is.finite(x)])` since the function is a one liner.